# Creating VMs (VMware) Automatically

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

We receive roughly 10 emails a day for new vm creations or take downs and I am wondering if its possible to create a webapp that would allow the customer to pick and choose what they need on this VM and click say "Create" and have it spin up by itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This already exists. There is an [API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/index.html) so that you can roll your own, or [vCloud Director](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcloud-director/overview.html) provides a self-service web portal for provisioning.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you could do with a basic installation of VMWare's [vCloud Director](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcloud-director/overview.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sure. vSphere has an API for such things. http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/index.html

Answer (score 3):

[uProvision](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/provision/) is a web application for automatically provisioning environments of VMware virtual machines, optionally within private networks. You can define templates for your desired configuration of virtual machines. It runs on top of an open-source command line provisioning tool called Terraform.

Disclaimer - I am a developer on uProvision and Terraform.

Comment: Just curious, what does this offer that vCloud Director doesn't?

Comment: It uses your own private vCenter instead of pay-as-you go, allows you to define templates, and allows you to automatically run post-create tasks on VMs. It also supports Amazon EC2, and Windows Azure and Rackspace integrations are in beta right now.

Comment: vCloud Directory uses your own private vCenter, though. It also lets you do all of that other stuff except EC2/Azure support.

Comment: Okay. I don't own vCloud so I was not aware.